# Morph path with Spring react ("arity problem" on d attribute)

Tags: react-spring

I got the "arity problem" with react-spring on this code:

```
<animated.path
                                    d={x.to({
                                        range: [0, 1],
                                        output: [
                                            ppath,
                                            ppath2,
                                        ],
                                    })}

                                />)
```

The exact error is

```
Error: The arity of each "output" value must be equal
```

The 2 paths are not empty and ok. I was wondering what if the arity problem with the "d" attribute. Are the 2 paths supposed to have the same number of element, curve ... ?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [docs](https://react-spring.io/basics#up-front-interpolation):

> SVG paths (as long as the number of points matches, otherwise use [custom interpolation](https://codesandbox.io/embed/lwpkp46om))